# uploading wordpress files to web host

Tags: wordpress, webserver, web-hosting, web-development-server

I have a hosting server subscription, and on that server I want to start building my Wordpress website, I just finished uploading the Wordpress files to the web host file manger,  and doing the configuration of database file, 
when I was about testing the Wordpress page, an error message poped out says: 
HTTP ERROR 500

could anyone tell what is this problem about? and how can I fix it?

Comment: Enable debugging to see if you can see error detail, or from debug log file. You can manage logging from `wp-config.php` https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: thank you @Mtxz , that was helpful